# sympy substitute all assigned variables

Tags: sympy, substitution

I declare a variable, define an expression using the variable

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols ('x')
f = 2 * x
```

and **then** assign a value to the variable

```
x = 42
```

How can I substitute the variable in the expression by its current value? For obvious reasons

```
f.subs (x, x)
```

does not work. I know that I can use a different variable

```
xx  = 42
f.subs (x, xx)
```

but ...

Nobody likes to get compared to their new girlfriend's ex, but in Matlab you could simply write `subs (f)` which would be the equivalent to SymPy's `f.subs ()` without any parameters, to substitute all intermediately assigned variables.

Comment: Well, sympy works differently.  Sympy has been carefully created to fit into an existing Python ecosystem.  In your case, you could try `f.subs ('x', x)`.  Note that if you write `x = symbols('x')`, and then `x = ....`, you remove your direct access to the symbol.  Matlab is a dedicated environment; each tool has its strong and weak points.  Feel free to choose the one that best fits your workflow.  By the way, a function that loops through an expression, looks up the variable names into the globals and does substitutions, wouldn't be that hard to write.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sympy "global" substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560362/sympy-global-substitution)

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71593718/901925

Comment: Johan, thank you, `f.subs ('x', x)` makes my life a bit easier. In aaguirre's [GlobalSubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560362/sympy-global-substitution) I still have to list all the variables I want to substitute. I am still dreaming of an automatic `f.subs()` that substitutes **all** currently assigned variables. But as you said, as soon as I understand a bit more about sympy, I will try to write that function ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

per above,

```
>>> f = x**2
>>> x = 42
>>> def update(e):
...     d = globals()
...     return e.xreplace({x: eval(x.name, d) for x in e.free_symbols})
>>> Eq(f, update(f))
x**2 = 1764
```

Comment: Wow, great, thanks a lot, Chris! Now give me a few days to understand what you did there ...

Comment: First question: what does `d = dir()` do? It seems to work without it.

Comment: Is the use of `globals()` as the second `eval` parameter necessary? With my limited knowledge, I cannot imagine any situation in this use case where omitting the reference to the current module namespace could be dangerous or critical.

Comment: I updated the code so `d` is used (and assigned `globals()`. Since you are passing the value to function it is safe. but if someone else had access to it I suppose they could name a symbol with some nefarious name which, when evaluated, would to bad things.